# How to draw a custom graphic on a map using ArcGIS JavaScript API?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server, esri-maps

I want each user to be able to draw their own area, and when they log on the next time they can automatically load this area. How can I achieve this function using ArcGIS JavaScript API and ArcGIS Server?

[image: the picture is about “The Climate Copration”]

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: i mean i don't know the direction to solve.i just want if some do the same thing can give me some advice .like books or something

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is clear that you want to draw some feature on the map and store this somwhere so that next time when use visits, he/she can see the last drawn feature on the map.

First of all you need to publish an editable feature layer in arcgis server where all the feature will be saved.

Below is the working sample for this-

```js
 var map;
      require([
        "esri/map",
        "esri/toolbars/draw",
        "esri/toolbars/edit",
        "esri/graphic",
        "esri/config",

        "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",

        "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
        "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol",

        "esri/dijit/editing/TemplatePicker",

        "dojo/_base/array",
        "dojo/_base/event",
        "dojo/_base/lang",
        "dojo/parser",
        "dijit/registry",

        "dijit/layout/BorderContainer", "dijit/layout/ContentPane",
        "dijit/form/Button", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, Draw, Edit, Graphic, esriConfig,
        FeatureLayer,
        SimpleMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleFillSymbol,
        TemplatePicker,
        arrayUtils, event, lang, parser, registry
      ) {
        parser.parse();

        // refer to "Using the Proxy Page" for more information:  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/ags_proxy.html
        esriConfig.defaults.io.proxyUrl = "/proxy/";

        // This service is for development and testing purposes only. We recommend that you create your own geometry service for use within your applications.
        esriConfig.defaults.geometryService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("https://utility.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-83.244, 42.581],
          zoom: 15
        });

        map.on("layers-add-result", initEditing);

        var landusePointLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/6", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
        var landuseLineLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/8", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });
        var landusePolygonLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Military/FeatureServer/9", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"]
        });

        map.addLayers([landusePointLayer, landuseLineLayer, landusePolygonLayer]);

        function initEditing(evt) {
          console.log("initEditing", evt);
          // var map = this;
          var currentLayer = null;
          var layers = arrayUtils.map(evt.layers, function(result) {
            return result.layer;
          });
          console.log("layers", layers);

          var editToolbar = new Edit(map);
          editToolbar.on("deactivate", function(evt) {
            currentLayer.applyEdits(null, [evt.graphic], null);
          });

          arrayUtils.forEach(layers, function(layer) {
            var editingEnabled = false;
            layer.on("dbl-click", function(evt) {
              event.stop(evt);
              if (editingEnabled === false) {
                editingEnabled = true;
                editToolbar.activate(Edit.EDIT_VERTICES , evt.graphic);
              } else {
                currentLayer = this;
                editToolbar.deactivate();
                editingEnabled = false;
              }
            });

            layer.on("click", function(evt) {
              event.stop(evt);
              if (evt.ctrlKey === true || evt.metaKey === true) {  //delete feature if ctrl key is depressed
                layer.applyEdits(null,null,[evt.graphic]);
                currentLayer = this;
                editToolbar.deactivate();
                editingEnabled=false;
              }
            });
          });

          var templatePicker = new TemplatePicker({
            featureLayers: layers,
            rows: "auto",
            columns: 2,
            grouping: true,
            style: "height: auto; overflow: auto;"
          }, "templatePickerDiv");

          templatePicker.startup();

          var drawToolbar = new Draw(map);

          var selectedTemplate;
          templatePicker.on("selection-change", function() {
            if( templatePicker.getSelected() ) {
              selectedTemplate = templatePicker.getSelected();
            }
            switch (selectedTemplate.featureLayer.geometryType) {
              case "esriGeometryPoint":
                drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POINT);
                break;
              case "esriGeometryPolyline":
                drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYLINE);
                break;
              case "esriGeometryPolygon":
                drawToolbar.activate(Draw.POLYGON);
                break;
            }
          });

          drawToolbar.on("draw-end", function(evt) {
            drawToolbar.deactivate();
            editToolbar.deactivate();
            var newAttributes = lang.mixin({}, selectedTemplate.template.prototype.attributes);
            var newGraphic = new Graphic(evt.geometry, null, newAttributes);
            selectedTemplate.featureLayer.applyEdits([newGraphic], null, null);
          });
        }
      });
```

```css
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow:hidden;
      }
      #header {
        border:solid 2px #462d44;
        background:#fff;
        color:#444;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 1.1em
        padding-left:20px;
      }
      #map {
        padding:1px;
        border:solid 2px #444;
        -moz-border-radius: 4px;
        border-radius: 4px;
      }
      #rightPane {
        border:none;
        padding: 0;
        width:228px;
      }
      .templatePicker {
        border: solid 2px #444;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/esri/css/esri.css">
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.20/"></script>
    
    <body class="claro">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="gutters:true, design:'headline'" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
      <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane"  id="header" data-dojo-props="region:'top'">Use ctrl or cmd + click on graphic to delete.  Double click on graphic to edit vertices. </div>
      <div id="map" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'center'"></div>
      <div id="rightPane" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" data-dojo-props="region:'right'">
        <div id="templatePickerDiv"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

**Update the proxy before you start consuming this sample.**

**Live running sample -**  https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=ed_feature_creation

**Hoping this will help you :)**

Comment: @merin is it helpful?